# IIS is hanging and needs to be recycled every time?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

We've one IIS application server on which we have deployed ASP.NET application.
Now the issue is Server is hanging very frequently and every time we are recycling or restarting application pool. Could you please help me to fix it.

**What I've tried:**

1) Looked into IIS log and found that there are few requests throwing 500 error some time. All the time except few instances same requests are working fine and getting 200 status.

2) Few resources are taking longer time like

```
a) "Report.aspx" - State- SendResponse - Time Elapsed- 2-3 minutes
I checked the query and found that sp is returning data in 00:00:02.
b) "NewReport.aspx" - State- ExecuteRequestHandler- Time Elapsed- 1 minutes
I checked the query and found that sp is returning data too quickly.
```

3) Default recycle time is 29 hrs, and each application is using individual pool.

4) In code application connection has been opened and not closed at very few places.

5) We are using connection pooling, having 2 different connection string with Max Pool=500 and min Pool=50 each.

6) Most of the time there is no error in Event Viewer, some time have received TCP/IP error.

**What I am looking for:**

1) Do I need to make any changes in IIS to track down or please help if any changes required in IIS?

2) Is there any setting in SQL Server which can help me to find out or fix it?

3) Please help if anything else I've to do to fix this issue from your previous experiences.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should capture a hang dump for W3WP.exe with Procdump or debug diagnostic tool first. We need to check all managed stack trace via **WINDBG, sos.dll and mex extension**. So that we can figure out worker thread is pending on which method and which module. Then might tell us about how to fix this hang issue. If you could find a way to always reproduce this problem. The problem would become much easier.

This link is about how to capture hang dump.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2014/01/09/debug-diagnostic-2-0-generate-a-manual-hang-dump-for-all-processes-owned-by-iis/

If you don't know how to analyze dump file manually, **debug diagnostic analysis tool** could help you achieve this.